# Prononciation de plus avec ou sans s dans un cas spécial

Tags: grammaire, prononciation, phonétique, coordination, francais-classique

Je voulais savoir si dans les phrases suivantes le "plus" est prononcé avec le s et c'est quoi la règle qui s'y applique.
"vous pouvez faire un don de 100$ ou plus selon vos moyens"
" Ce cours est réservé pour les personnes ages de 50 ans et plus et pour les personnes a mobilité réduite.
Merci

Answer (score 0):

Dans les deux cas le s est prononcé. Dans le cas de la phrase suivante il n'est pas prononcé.

- Pour un don de plus de 100$ votre nom sera publié."

[Parlez-vous French](https://parlez-vous-french.com/comment-prononcer-plus-en-francais/)

Comment: D'accord merci beaucoup !!